# how to change background image on button at runtime in android

Tags: android, image, dynamic, background

Hi i'm a new android developer,
I tried the change background image when i click button at run time using R.drawable.image1,
Then i clicked button display the another image,how to change image name,
but images name declared string array,How to change the image ,Using

setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images)

Please any one help to me and solve my problem

Comment: you want to change the walpaper of your phone?

Comment: i have lot of images in my drawable folder,clik button change the image from drawable folder

Comment: Yes i know that,you want to change walpaper or image view content?

Comment: change imageview background in my application

Comment: declare your array as array of integer

Comment: but i click button how to change R.drawable.(this name)

Comment: the images name in database ,example image name(at111,at112,at113,...) how to display the images

Comment: that's simple see my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7                    
    };
```

and call `imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);`

Comment: String imgname="resources" + "pic1"; int resources=getResources().getIdentifier(imgname,"drawable","com.google") its possible to display the particular image

Comment: @mohamed no you can't do that!! absolutely wrong R.drawable.nameofpicture is a hardcoded integer that you can find under gen/R.java

Comment: ,i designed the page when i click the button call one class,for example i have lot of images in my drawable folder,but i display the particular image in that class,go back and click the class i display another image ,ple help me K_Anas

Comment: @mohamed sorry but can you explain with a simple way, I can't understand what you really want!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13534/discussion-between-k-anas-and-mohamed)